# How to Clone the Entity object and all of its associated entities values aswell with EF in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, clone

I have a entity "Player" that has "one to many" association to other entities. When I clone one of my Player rows the entities that are associated with Player are not getting cloned. but the Player data row gets cloned. I need the assocations values to get cloned aswell. How can I do this?

Here is the code inside my respository

```
public Player CreateTemplate(Player player)
{
db.Detach(player);
Player.EntityKey = null;
db.AddToPlayer(player);
db.SaveChanges();
return player;
}
```

Here is my Action method:

```
public ActionResult CreatePlayerTemplate(int id)
{
var player = MyRepository.GetPlayerdByID(id);
MyRepository.CreateTemplate(player);
return View();
}
```

Update:
this how i retrieve `Player` :

```
 public Player GetPlayerByID(int id)
    {
        return db.Player.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative, kinda hacky approach - use mapping tool, like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Define self-maps for every entity participating in cloning, and configure to ignore entity key

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Player, Player>()
.ForMember(x => x.EntityKey, y => y.Ignore());

Mapper.CreateMap<SomeOtherEntity, SomeOtherEntity>()
.ForMember(x => x.EntityKey, y => y.Ignore());
```

And then just clone entities

```
var clonnedPlayer = Mapper.Map<Player>(originalPlayer);
```

Also, this way you could configure  not to clone lookup-like tables to not duplicate lookup data

Comment: If I update my question with picture of my entity model. Could you show me an example on how to use automapper?

Comment: @ps__ the basic setup is trivial, you could just take a look at http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 2):

You need to also detach all of the associated entities as the detach method above only detaches the player.

You also need to make sure you null the PKs of each of these entitys to ensure you dont perform a duplicate key insert

```
public Player CreateTemplate(Player player)
{
   db.Detach(player);
   foreach(var thing in player.Things)
   {
      context.Detach(thing);
      thing.EntityKey = null;
   }
   Player.EntityKey = null;
   db.AddToPlayer(player);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return player;
}
```

Comment: How will my method look like? Beacuse I cant insert more than one object in my detach it seems like

Comment: @ps__ see edit, you will need something that loops and detaches sub entites. AddToPlayer will re-add the sub-entities later

Comment: so basically "things" on your example could be Player.Selectedteams?
SelectedTeam is a entity that has many to one association with Player

Comment: I've tried the loop in this method. But it won't loop through Player.SelectedTeams because `var thing` is null.

Comment: I think you mean player.Things is null, You will need to include them first, when you get a player use `.Include(p=>p.SelectedTeams)` to retrieve them as well.

Comment: I've updated the question to show you how I retrieve player. Could you explain to me how I should include `SelectedTeams` in my `GetPlayerByID`.

Comment: `return db.Player.Include(p=>p.SelectedTeams).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);` and make sure you are using System.Data.Entity

Comment: It's still not working can it be beacuse SelectedTeams is a navigation property? It must be the reason :S