# foreach loop not working correctly when to save copy of entity in MVC with entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have MVC3 project where I use Entity Framework
I have entity with `player` that user should be able to make copy of.

To make a copy of `player` I have the following in my repository:

```
public Player CreateTemplate(Player player)
    {
        var copy = new Player();

        copy.Birth_Date = player.birth_Date;
        copy.Comment = player.Comment;
        copy.Name = player.Name;
        copy.Agent = player.Agent;
        copy.AgentId = player.AgentId;
        foreach (SelectedTeams selectedTeams in player.SelectedTeams.ToList())
        {
            var copyselectedteams = new SelectedTeams();
            copyselectedteams = selectedTeams;
            copy.SelectedTeams.Add(copyselectedteams);
        }
        db.AddToPlayer(copy);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return copy;
    }
```

The problem for me is, that once my foreach starts looping, my original `player` lose it's `SelectedTeams`
Is there any solutions is for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Clone the Entity object and all of its associated entities values aswell with EF in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515515/how-to-clone-the-entity-object-and-all-of-its-associated-entities-values-aswell)

Comment: SelectedTeams as class name and collection name, very confusing! Do you want to copy the SelectedTeams's as well, or only copy the references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do You have Lazy Loading disabled by any chance?
You may try to eager load entity like this:

```
var firstPlayer = dbContext.Players.Include("SelectedTeams").FirstOrDefault<Player>(p => p.PlayerId == 1);
var copiedPlayer = repo.CreateTemplate(firstPlayer);
```

Also You shouldn't copy references of existing entities to new entity.

```
copyselectedteams = selectedTeams;
```

Instead copy its properties (except relationship keys of course or You will get exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the reference to the new object you just created:

```
var copyselectedteams = new SelectedTeams(); //overwritten...
copyselectedteams = selectedTeams; //...here
```

Comment: Could you give an example on how to not overwrite and instead pass the reference to the new object so the original object wont get affected by the override